# Evaluating expression with $parse in directive inside an ng-repeat in Angular 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I'm trying to use `$parse` the expression of an attribute of a directive within an ng-repeat.
Here's a simple HTML:

```
<body ng-app="hello" ng-controller="control">
<div ng-repeat="a in array" my-dir="a.one == 1"></div>
</body>
```

and the Angular directive:

```
angular.module('hello', [])
.controller('control', function($scope){
  $scope.array = [{
    one: 1,
    two: 2
  },
  {
    one: 3,
    two: 4
  }];
})
.directive('myDir', function($parse){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      var hash = $parse(attrs.myDiv);
      // I would like a way of evaluating this expression
      // without having to use things like my-dir="array[$index].item == 1"
      // just like one would do with other angular directives.
      console.log(hash(scope)); // This is undefined, because a.one can not be found in scope.
    },
  };

});
```

The issue with doing this is that `$parse` is using `scope` to look for the `a.one` property and obviously that doesn't exist.

I could do `my-dir="array[$index].one == 1"` but it's not intuitive for the users of the directive (they will have to consider the scope in which they're calling the directive).

Comment: So, you can require parent scope via require: ?ngModel.

Answer (score 0):

There is typo - `myDiv` instead `myDir`.
http://plnkr.co/edit/rwoUXjxmvmdTp3OIE4Yo?p=preview